# Updating token smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to update my token smart contract and I want to send new tokens to actual holders. Any code or ideas about how to do this? Contract is deployed, but I have not idea how to send tokens to actual holders. Also, how can I blacklist those scammers that took our token from the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Once a contract is deployed, you can't change it unless you have some mechanism in place to do this. If your current contract does not have this, there's nothing you can do. However, for future reference, you could try something like this:

```
contract SomeContract {
    address public owner;

    address public currentContract;

    function SomeContract(address initContract){
        currentVersion = initContract;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function update(address newAddress){
        if(msg.sender != owner) throw;
        currentVersion = newAddress;
    }

    function myFunction(){
        currentContract.delegatecall(msg.data)
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use the actual token them, If I want to create a airdrop system for holders every certain time,